# Verifying Error after ADT Update

Tags: android, adt, verifyerror

I have a project that worked for months, but I updated the ADT Plugin a few days ago and today all of a sudden the project stopped working. If I try to run it on the device, it throws a VerifyError as soon as it is started.

(the xxx is a replacement for the actual of the project name because I'm not allowed to publish it)

These kind of error repeat themself, so I just post one. The main VerifyError itself is useless since it just points at the main starting Activity.

```
05-03 18:06:59.898: I/dalvikvm(26640): Could not find method org.osmdroid.views.MapView.enableScroll, referenced from method com.xxx.activities.MainAc.disableSwipe
05-03 18:06:59.898: D/dalvikvm(26640): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0005
05-03 18:06:59.898: D/dalvikvm(26640): VFY: dead code 0x0008-0010 in Lcom/xxx/activities/MainAc;.disableSwipe ()V
05-03 18:06:59.898: W/dalvikvm(26640): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/osmdroid/util/GeoPoint;)
05-03 18:06:59.898: E/dalvikvm(26640): Could not find class 'org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint', referenced from method com.xxx.activities.MainAc.displayPointNavigation
05-03 18:06:59.908: W/dalvikvm(26640): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 575 (Lorg/osmdroid/util/GeoPoint;) in Lcom/xxx/activities/MainAc;
05-03 18:06:59.908: D/dalvikvm(26640): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0018
05-03 18:06:59.908: D/dalvikvm(26640): VFY: dead code 0x001a-0093 in Lcom/xxx/activities/MainAc;.displayPointNavigation (Lorg/osmdroid/util/GeoPoint;)V
05-03 18:06:59.908: W/dalvikvm(26640): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/xxx/overlay/MyUpmoveLocationOverlay; (584)
```

I think the problem is the way I included the osmdroid lib. Since I have to change a lot of osmdroid code, I didn't want to build a jar all the time, so I created a Java Project from the osmdroid source and added the osmdroid Project to my Project's Classpath.

Until now this setup worked like a charm. I thought that I may have changed something myself that caused the VerifyError, so I reverted the project to a revision where it definitly was working but I get the same error.

Are there some settings I have to change to make this work again or do I have to redo the whole setup and include the osmdroid as a jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make OSMDroid be an [Android library project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject) and add it as a library to your main application project.

Comment: ok, if nobody has another solution I'm gonna try that ... man I really despise updating the ADT now ... 2nd time that after updating nothing works like before :(